# BigQuery: Xoring Elements of Two Arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have a two arrays.

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

b = [11, 22, 33, 44]

How can I xor the respective elements of two arrays to get a result as

result = [10, 20 ,34, 40] i-e 1^11 = 10, 2^22=20 and so on

I have tried BIT_XOR(x) but it takes one array and xor all of the elements of array.

```
SELECT BIT_XOR(x) AS bit_xor FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4]) AS x;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "zip" the two arrays together:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT x ^ b[OFFSET(off)]
    FROM UNNEST(a) AS x WITH OFFSET off) AS bit_xor
FROM dataset.table
```

This combines the elements based on their offset in the two arrays.

Comment: Awesome :)  Thank you so much brother :)